# Returning Art Canvas name and Size inside a query

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

Hi Guys I need some help here on a project that I am currently working on this is the index function on a controller in my Web App that I have made for a client that everything is working fine but I need to return the title and size of the canvas with the image here is my controller code

```
    public function index(){
    $query_result = $this->Art_m->get_art();
    error_log(count($query_result));

    $canvas = '';
    $counter = 0;


    foreach($query_result as $row) {
        $title = $row['canvas_name'];
        $image = $row['canvas_image'];
        $size = $row['canvas_size'];
        error_log($title . $image . $size);

        if($counter == 0){

            $canvas .= '<div class="item">
            <a rel="prettyPhoto" class="thumbnail" href="' . base_url() . 'data/uploads/canvases/' . $image . '" alt="' . $title . '">
                <img src="' . base_url() . 'data/uploads/canvases/' . $image . '" alt="' . $title . '"/>
            </a>
            </div>';
        } else {
            $canvas .= '<div class="item">
            <a rel="prettyPhoto" class="thumbnail" href="' . base_url() . 'data/uploads/canvases/' . $image . '" alt="' . $title . '">
                <img src="' . base_url() . 'data/uploads/canvases/' . $image . '" alt="' . $title . '"/>
            </a>
            </div>';
        }
        $counter++;
    }
    $data['canvas'] = $canvas;
    $data['title'] = 'Ali Cockburn Abstract Art';
    $data['art'] = $this->Art_m->get_art();
    $data['content'] = 'art_view';
    $this->load->view('templates/site/template',$data);
}
```

The code works perfectly, but how do I echo out the `$title` and `$size` above the `<a>` tag inside of a `<p>` tag? Can someone please assist?

Comment: You mean you have to print the Title and Canvas along ith the Image or somewher near the Image inside the html ?

Comment: In my html I currently just echo out $canvas and it shows the image so in the <div class="item"> section i would like to echo out the title and size in a p tag

Comment: `$canvas .= '<div class="item">
            <a rel="prettyPhoto" class="thumbnail" href="' . base_url() . 'data/uploads/canvases/' . $image . '" alt="' . $title . '">
                <img src="' . base_url() . 'data/uploads/canvases/' . $image . '" alt="' . $title . '"/>
            </a><p>Title : '.$title.' , canvas : '.$size.'</p>
            </div>';`

Comment: Thank you Kiran appreciate the help tremendously

Comment: Welcome !   instead passing the HTML code itself to view, you can pass only the values in $data array. In view you can generate the html and echo values inside the html tags . Refer this : https://selftaughtcoders.com/displaying-data-codeigniter-view/

Comment: I usually do it that way but in this instance it does not want to work that way hehehe